# React conditional rendering with functions and variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, react-component

I'm trying to make a render of a HTML element stored in a variable in a function component in React. This element should render only after the user successfully used a form to send data, acting as a confirmation message. So the idea was to store this message in a variable, which is null if the user didn't use the form (so it won't be rendered) and is a paragraph if the user completed the form. I understand that in order to do this I should update the state of the component to cause a re-render, but I can't make it work for some reason: i can update the state just fine, but the JSX stored in that variable does not appear, even in the Elements tab of developer tools, like it's not getting rendered at all.

This is the code for my component "Contacts":

```
export default function Contacts() 
{

    const [toSend, setToSend] = useState({
        from_name: '',
        to_name: '',
        message: '',
        reply_to: '',
        confirmation: null
    });

    const validateAndSend = () =>
    {
        let isValid = true;
        let stop = false;

        const elementList = document.querySelectorAll("input"); 
        elementList.forEach( 
            (e) => {
                if (e.value === ("") && stop === false)  
              {
                alert("You must fill every field of the form!");
                isValid = false;
                stop = true;
              }
            }
        );

        if (isValid === true)
        {
            send(   
                'service_id',  
                'template_id', /
                toSend,
                'user_id') 
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log("Email sent successfully!", response.status, response.text);
            })
            .catch( (err) => {
                console.log('Error sending email: ', err);
            });

            const confirmationComponent = (<p id="confirm_message">Email sent successfully to website's administrator. You will be contacted at the email address you've just provided.</p>) ;
            setToSend({ ...toSend, confirmation: { confirmationComponent } });
        };

    };

    const handleChange = (e) =>
    {
        setToSend({ ...toSend, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    };


    return (
        <div className="contacts">
            <NavBar />
            <h1>Contact us!</h1>
            { toSend.confirmation }
            <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={(event) => { event.preventDefault(); } }>
                <input type="text" name="from_name" placeholder="from name" value={toSend.from_name} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="to_name" placeholder="to name" value={toSend.to_name} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Your message" value={toSend.message} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="reply_to" placeholder="Your email" value={toSend.reply_to} onChange={handleChange} />

                <button type='submit' onClick={ validateAndSend }>Send</button>
            </form>
            <CustomFooter />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm more familiar with class components: i would declare this confirmationComponent as a class variable in the class constructor to give it a scope of visibility to all the methods of the class, render() included, then I would update the state after the form gets sent by the user and I would then see the component generated (called as { this.confirmationComponent } in the return of the render() method.

I know function components are very similar, but I can't make it work...

I had also the idea of declaring a global function variable "var confirmationComponent" initializing it to null, and then change it to the paragraph after the validation; the components should update after doing a "useless" setState in this way:  setToSend({ ...toSend, confirmation: true });

So it would be:

```
export default function Contacts() 
{
    var confirmationComponent = null;

    const [toSend, setToSend] = useState({
        from_name: '',
        to_name: '',
        message: '',
        reply_to: '',
        confirmation: null
    });

    const validateAndSend = () =>
    {
        let isValid = true;
        let stop = false;

        const elementList = document.querySelectorAll("input"); 
        elementList.forEach(  /* Controllo se sono stati compilati tutti i campi del form */
            (e) => {
                if (e.value === ("") && stop === false)  
              {
                alert("You must fill every field of the form!");
                isValid = false;
                stop = true;
              }
            }
        );

        if (isValid === true)
        {
            send(   
                'service_ID',  
                'template_ID', 
                toSend,
                'user_ID') 
            .then( (response) => {
                console.log("Email sent successfully!", response.status, response.text);
            })
            .catch( (err) => {
                console.log('Error sending email: ', err);
            });

            confirmationComponent = (<p id="confirm_message">Email sent successfully to website's administrator. You will be contacted at the email address you've just provided.</p>) ;
            setToSend({ ...toSend, confirmation: true });
        };

    };

    const handleChange = (e) =>
    {
        setToSend({ ...toSend, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    };


    return (
        <div className="contacts">
            <NavBar />
            <h1>Contact us!</h1>
            { confirmationComponent }
            <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={(event) => { event.preventDefault(); } }>
                <input type="text" name="from_name" placeholder="from name" value={toSend.from_name} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="to_name" placeholder="to name" value={toSend.to_name} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Your message" value={toSend.message} onChange={handleChange} />
                <input type="text" name="reply_to" placeholder="Your email" value={toSend.reply_to} onChange={handleChange} />

                <button type='submit' onClick={ validateAndSend }>Send</button>
            </form>
            <CustomFooter />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, neither this solution does work, and that paragraph never gets rendered. The email is sent successfully, though, and the assignment to the variable confirmationComponent does aswell.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question asked. But there is no reason to use `document.querySelectorAll("input")` here. You already have all the values within the `toSend` state. So `const isValid = Object.values(toSend).all(value => value !== "")` would do perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, Is this a React anti-patten? I'm not manipulating the DOM, just accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason why it doesn't render has to do with: The first letter of the component name should be capitalized. Source https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Can you try:

```
const Confirmation = toSend.confirmation;
```

just before `return` in the first method, and then render it in the return block by writing in JSX form:

```
<Confirmation />
```